# Meaning of $\int_{a}^{b}dx$

Tags: calculus

I know the meaning of $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$, which is $F(b)-F(a)$. Geometrically, it gives us the area under the graph from $x=a$ to $x=b$

But what does $\int_{a}^{b}dx$ mean mathematically with respect to $f(b)-f(a)$ and what is its geometrical meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_a^bdx$ would simply be the same as $\int_a^b 1\ dx$, so it would be the area under the curve $f(x)=1$, which is indeed equal to the length of the segment from $a$ to $b$, i.e., $b-a$.

Answer (score 1):

It has the same meaning as for any other function, here $f(x) = 1$, the constant function at $1$, so $\int_a^b dx$ gives the area of the rectangle with side lengths $(b-a)$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

You could read  $\int_a^b \, dx$ is an operator, taking a function and returning a value:
$$
 f \mapsto \int_a^b f \, dx
$$
The usual intended reading of $\int_a^b \, dx$ is however $\int_a^b  1 \, dx$
which then simply equates to$(b -a)$ after doing the integration.

Comment: Thanks. I will correct my mistake.